# How to get AngularJS value

Tags: html, angularjs, playframework

I have this code that increment the number "count":

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
```

And I want the number "count" control det index of this list:

```
<p>@month.get({{count}})</p>
```

But this way isn't work..

Comment: what is @month.get()???? else everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the get inside your controller, and then you can just display the result.

In the html:

```
<p>Month: {{getMonth(count)}}</p>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.getMonth = function (m) {
    return month[m];
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10077/) using a simple list of months - you can replace the getMonth function with whatever is needed to get your particular data.

Comment: Do you now how I set var month to my scala list? I send it to the html like this @(month: List[String])

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala, but a typical approach would be to have a simple rest service on your server side which prints the list, and then get that in your angular controller using $http or $resource (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).